# What is the correct XPath query for 'select onchange'

Tags: xpath

I'm learning XPath and looking to extract the URL embedded within the following HTML. I've tried variants of `@"//table[contains(@option, 'value')]"` without success.

```
<body>
<div id="Wrapper">
<div id="header">
<span id="logoHolder">
<a href="http://www.foo.com">
<img src="/templates/blank_j15/images/nexus_logo.png" width="167" height="65" border="0"/>
</a>
</span>
<span style="float: left; padding-top: 27px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; color: rgb(0, 182, 222); ">Embracing Diversity. Challenging Minds.</span>
<span id="searchHolder">
<div style="clear: both; "/>
<div id="IE_P_space"/>
<div id="arttotalmenucontent_138" class="hidden">
<script type="text/javascript">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" id="wrapper_cont_table">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top" id="wrapper_cont_leftNav">
<div class="leftnavCont">
<p>
<select onchange="nl(this.value)" size="8">
<option value="/images/download/newsletter/connect04_300911.pdf">Connect 04: 30/09/2011</option>
<option value="/images/download/newsletter/connect03_230911.pdf">Connect 03: 23/09/2011</option>
<option value="/images/download/newsletter/connect02_150911.pdf">Connect 02: 15/09/2011</option>
<option value="/images/download/newsletter/connect01_120911.pdf">Connect 01: 12/09/2011</option>
</p>
```

Comment: Your selector reads as - "select all table nodes who have an `option` attribute that contains the string `value`". Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, I've even tried @"//div[@class='leftnavCont']" but that too doesn't work.

Comment: There's more than one URL in there. Which one are you after?

Comment: I'm after the <option value> that are embedded within the <p><select></p>.

Comment: You can select attribute nodes much like you select element nodes:  Would something like `//p/select/option/@value` do the trick?

Comment: Hi Xavier, tried //p/select/option/@value but it didn't work which is perplexing. I've never encountered <select onchange> before.

Comment: @Globalnomad, you've mentioned that things didn't work, but you haven't told us what result you got. This makes it difficult to test possible diagnoses. E.g. do you get an empty nodeset for the result? One important piece of info is the default namespace in the (X?)HTML. Can you show us what the `<html>` start tag looks like? If there is a default namespace (e.g. XHTML) then you won't be able to select anything with XPath without declaring a namespace.

Comment: Also, as Oded alluded to, and I don't think you understood, `@option` refers to an **attribute** named `option`. But you're trying to look at **elements** named `option`. In addition, the `contains()` function tests whether a **string** contains another string as a substring. But you seem to be using it to ask whether an **element** (`table`) has another element (`option`) as a descendant. It feels like you're throwing darts while blindfolded. I think you will find it much faster to read a primer on XPath and then try again, than to keep trying with such little idea of what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//p/select/option/@value
```

Seems to work for me.

I think there must be a problem with the usage of your xpath library. It didn't take me long to find the source of your sample.

Here's a working example with my xml library of preference.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
from urllib2 import urlopen
from lxml import etree

filename = 'sample.html'
url = 'http://www.foo.example/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=186&Itemid=301'
# Some simple caching for a test script...
if os.path.exists(filename):
  with open(filename,'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
else:
  data  = urlopen(url).read()
  with open(filename,'w') as f:
    f.write(data)

doc = etree.HTML(data)

for v in doc.xpath('//p/select/option/@value'):
  print v
```

Produces:

```
/images/download/newsletter/connect04_300911.pdf
/images/download/newsletter/connect03_230911.pdf
/images/download/newsletter/connect02_150911.pdf
/images/download/newsletter/connect01_120911.pdf
```